# What to use instead of "com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.hash.Hashing"?

Tags: google-app-engine

I used "com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.hash.Hashing" in my project so far, but since a while I get "Use of com.google.appengine.repackaged may result in your app breaking without warning" error. What is best to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

I used guava library com.google.common.hash.Hashing. It worked.